# Creating a Search interface in ASP.NET MVC - C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]

The above is concept of a search interface I want to build in ASP.net MVC. when user clicks on the '+' button, it should create a row text filters or date filters. Does jQuery offer me this flexibility or are there any such UI frameworks which would help me achieve this? There is a search button, not shown, which when clicked should post back and obtain results and display the results

Comment: What software did you use to make the UI mockup?  I like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create dynamic form. Just use the Jquery .append to add new elements to your form.

```
$("#myform").append("<input type='text' name='textfield'>")
```

Comment: I agree. You're going to need a custom implementation and the dynamic form provides an elegant solution.

Comment: Tony: Thanks for the info. Any good tutorials to start off with?

Answer (score 0):

A little difficult to visualise what you are talking about as it doesn't show in the question.

But if I understand your question then you want to click on a button and show some filter fields right?

This is do-able not only in jQuery but in just standard javascript.  All you need to do is unhide the filter elements.

jQuery will give you a nice way to scroll it open though and then you could do a partial post back and just return the results or partial view.

```
$("#divFilters").slideDown(300);
```

The code above will open your div.

Or you could jQuery a partial postback, return RenderPartial from your controller and replace the html in a div somewhere.  The RenderPartail would be a partial view with your filters in it.  Easier to extend at a later date too I'd have thought.

Is this what you were after?

Comment: This is a pretty good starting point http://jquery.com/.

If you want actual code then let me know, in a comment here, and I'll post some.